# Does the navigation controls and other controls have to be within the appDelegate?

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to start your project with a single view controller, then on the second or third view controller implement the navigation controller, then maybe on the forth view controller implement the tab view controller?  Or does this type of project need to be a storyboard project?

My dilema at the moment is that I start with just one single view controller that has a round rect button that takes you to the second view controller.  From the second view controller, I would like a navigation controller with an embedded table view that will take me back and fourth from the second to the third view controller.  I've been trying for hours putting the necessary code into each .h and .m file but I keep hitting brick walls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

a. You can of course present several regular view controllers then add a `UINavigationController` at a later stage. When you need to present the navigation controller, you can embed your detail view controller inside one as follows:

(code is in the view controller which you want to display the detail view controller from)

```
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];
[self presentViewController:detailNav animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

b. It is not allowed to have a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController` (or any other view controller). You can however still use the `UITabBar` control and manage the rest. For an example of this, please refer to [UITabBarController inside a UINavigationController](http://www.alexmedearis.com/uitabbarcontroller-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/).

Comment: Hi Matt, thats very informative thanks!  I guessed you couldn't have a UITabBarController nested inside a UINavigationaController, but if you can implement a UINavigationController later down the line, then a UITabBarController even later down the line thats great and pretty much answers my question.  So how come when implementing the UINavigationController in the appDelegate, you have to have a UINavigationController property in the .h file, in fact do I need one in my first single view .h file as well as the code you provided?  Many thanks!

Comment: You actually only need a UINavigationController property only if you create the UINavigationController in Interface Builder (in order to retain the created object). If you'll be creating the UINavigationController in code, you do not need a property at all in your appDelegate.